# ASP.NET Core - How do I detect if my IHostedService crashes at runtime? Can I restart it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm implementing a timed background service in my ASP.NET Core web site, using the code found at [this blog post](https://leeconlin.co.uk/blog/recurring-tasks-in-net-core-20-without-a-scheduling-library) as a model. The bit that does the real work looks like the following...

```
protected async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Put your code here

        // Wait 30 minutes before running again.
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

This works fine until something causes the service to crash. Obviously, in a production application you'd hope that this wouldn't happen, but being practical, I need to account for the possibility.

As far as I can see, the framework creates and starts the task, and the rest of the app doesn't know anything about it. Can I detect if the `IHostedService` service crashes, and can I restart it? If not, what do I do? Having this run at regular intervals is crucial to the web site, so I need to know I can handle any problems.

Comment: Well the simplest solution is to wrap the while loop in a try catch block. Why don't you do that?

Comment: @Silvermind I already have that, but it seems an inelegant way to do it. Just wondered if there was anything more elegant. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to detect the service status, you may consider try `try catch block`.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel If you don't want to catch the entire block of code, then just figure out why it crashes, and make it stop.

Comment: How did you host it? I am facing trouble in deploying HostedService in IIS

Comment: @AdritaSharma I ended up not using the hosted services, and using Quartz.NET instead, as that seemed much more stable. It fires a new job each schedule, rather than relying on the same job running forever, so if anything unhandled did go wrong, it didn't affect subsequent runs.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Thanks.. I will look into it too

Answer (score -3):

> If not, what do I do? Having this run at regular intervals is crucial to the web site, so I need to know I can handle any problems.

You should be running critical background services *in a separate, independent process*. This can be Azure Functions or Docker or even a Win32 service with auto-restart enabled. This way, *something else* restarts your process as necessary.